# Dynamic Assignment to PLSQL Type variable

Tags: plsql

I have a scenario where I have to perform dynamic assignment to PLSQL type variable.

For example, below is a simple assignment of value to type `my_tab_type`. `fn_get_value(varchar2)` function returns value based on string passed.

```
my_tab_type.table_name.LEAD   := fn_get_value('LEAD_ID');
```

Like these there will be hundreds of assignments. I want to store the mapping (LEAD,LEAD_ID) in a table, fetch these mapped values in a cursor and dynamically create assignment statement.

I want to avoid `execute immediate` or `dbms_sql.execute` for each dynamic assignment created as performance will be affected. Please help me come up with an feasible and effective approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You might have a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

You don't tell us the types in your question so I assume [nested table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99981) of [records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00509).

You can't assign a PL/SQL record "dynamically" without using dynamic PL/SQL (i.e. running PL/SQL with `execute immediate`). This also means that all uses of such "dynamically" created record have to take place dynamically. That's not the way PL/SQL is supposed to be used.

However if you can change your data type to [associative array](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99969) you can archive your goal with a plain boring static well-mannered PL/SQL !

Below you'll find an example that should get you started.

**Example**

```
create table so60 (
 from_ varchar2(20)
,to_ varchar2(20)
);

insert into so60 values('A_FROM', 'A_TO');
insert into so60 values('B_FROM', 'B_TO');
insert into so60 values('C_FROM', 'C_TO');

declare
  -- foo_t is an associative array
  type foo_t is table of varchar2(32767) index by varchar2(32767);
  v_foo foo_t;

  function f(p_x in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  begin
    return lower(p_x);
  end;
begin
  -- initialize from table
  for i in (select * from so60)
  loop
    v_foo(i.to_) := f(i.from_);
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_foo('B_TO'));
end;
/
```

**Example run**

```
SQL> @so60
b_from

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```